# geopandas controls legend size when using xlim, ylim

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

I try to create a geopanda plot where I need to set specific values for `xlim` and `ylim`. It works but the legend is huge now. I would prefer for it to be as large as the actual plotted map, but can't seem to figure out how to control this behaviour.

**Minimal working example**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas; print(geopandas.__version__)
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')

world.plot(ax=ax, column='2015', legend=True,
           legend_kwds={'label': "Population", 'orientation': "horizontal"})
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = -12, 30, 30,80 
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
ax.margins(0)
ax.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

plt.savefig('sample.png', bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```

[image: Resulting graph, with "too large" legend]

Comment: How `world` variable is defined?

Comment: it ships with the module; ran the code to see

Comment: If I run your example, `world` is not defined. are you sure you didn't import it from somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't really *run* your attached code, as it says that `world` is not defined. But in any case, you could try the solution provided by the official docs [here](https://geopandas.org/mapping.html#creating-a-legend). It is specifically stated that:

> However, the default appearance of the legend and plot axes may **not** be **desirable**. One can define the plot axes (with ax) and the legend axes (with cax) and then pass those in to the plot call.

Nevertheless, for your case you should try this:

```
... # Your imports as they are
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)  # Define 'divider' for the axes
# Legend axes will be located at the 'bottom' of figure, with width '5%' of ax and
# a padding between them equal to '0.1' inches 
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0.1)

world.plot(ax=ax, column='2015', legend=True,
           legend_kwds={'label': "Population", 'orientation': "horizontal"},
           cax=cax)
           ^^^^^^^  # Add cax in the list of 'plot' arguments

... # Rest code as it is
```

For example, with your code and the *additions* to it I mentioned above, for `world` *GeoDataFrame* as:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

and `column='pop_est'` the output is:

[image]

---

### Brief explanation

[AxesGrid toolkit](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#what-is-axesgrid-toolkit) is a collection of helper classes, mainly to ease displaying (multiple) images in *Matplotlib*. The docs state that:

> In matplotlib, the axes location (and size) is specified in the normalized figure coordinates, which may not be ideal for displaying images that needs to have a given aspect ratio. **For example, it helps you to have a colorbar whose height always matches that of the image.**

So, in pure *Matplotlib* is more difficult to interfere in matching the sizes of a *figure* and a *colorbar* axes. With [`AxesDivider`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesdivider) class of the toolkit you can easily **sync** the axes of a colorbar with the *master axes* of figure, as illustrated above.